# Dynamic web project won't run on tomcat as a whole but .java runs on server just fine. Why?

Tags: java, web-development-server

I am working on a dynamic web project in eclipse. All of a sudden the tomcat server would not run my project when I select the project as a whole and use run on server. But when I went into the src and selected my .java file and tried to run it on server the project was deployed successfully. What I am doing wrong ?

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: You need to add URL in welcome file list in web.xml otherwise it throws 404 status.

Comment: If it stopped all of a sudden, try cleaning up the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the times while deploying the project, we forgets to clean and build the project.
So, Try these steps before deploying a project, which may helps in your case -

```
Shut down the Apache Tomcat server.
Clean and build the project.
Deploy the project.
Run the project using your default URL.
```